# Record type and page layout

Tags: record-type, record

All users are unable to directly update Billing Address and Shipping Address
 on the Account page for all but "A" record type.

There are 7 page layout and 4 record type. All are existed. A record type has  page layout assigned . What to do ?

Comment: Is that a situation now or what you want to achieve?

Comment: This is the situation. user will be able to edit address fields for one record type only where under other record type address will be read only

Comment: Is each RT is using a different Page Layout?

Comment: The one RT that user can edit has one page layout but other records type has different page layout

Answer (score 2):

Two ways you have to implement.

1) Make that field as read-only on the page layout where user will not be editing the address.

2) Also, you need to create validation rule based on recordtype where user cannot be able to edit the address.

```
RecordType.Name = "Your Account Recordtype" 
&& (ISCHANGED(BillingStreet) || ISCHANGED(BillingState) .....)
```

then throw the validation error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment: "The one RT that user can edit has one page layout but other records type has different page layout", I think your problem is that the address field is simply marked R/O for one Page Layout, but not for the other.

It is not clear to me whether you are trying to allow all RTs to be editable, or none, but the Page Layout is clearly where the disconnect is happening.

You have a few choices here:

a) As @Santanu Boral specified above, the easiest fix is to edit the Page Layouts so the field in every one of them is either R/O or not. That will give you consistency

b) If you still need some profiles to edit the Billing Address for RT "A" (but not others), your other choice is to go into "Page Layout Assignment" and map the existing R/O Page Layout to the profiles that need the R/O access.

c) If both existing page layouts are different, consider going into the one that is currently editable, change the Billing Address field to R/O and then "Save As..." (instead of Save). This will create a new Page Layout that you can then assign as outlined in step b).

I hope this helps you!

PS: R/O = Read Only.